Retrieve source address with `recvmsg` and `io_uring`
I'm trying to build an example io_uring echo udp server here. Basically since recv_from is not available, I need to use recvmsg and somehow retrieve the source address to respond.
My first question is why this work:
let mut msg_hdr: libc::msghdr = unsafe { std::mem::zeroed() };
// I copied this from tokio/io-uring test code, I don't know why it works
// https://github.com/tokio-rs/io-uring/blob/master/io-uring-test/src/tests/net.rs
msg_hdr.msg_namelen = 16;

// receive the msg...

let msg_out = types::RecvMsgOut::parse(&vec[buf_start..buf_end], &msg_hdr).unwrap();

println!("msg_out: {:?}", msg_out);

If I set msg_namelen to anything but 0 and 16 then I get parsing errors. If I set to 0 the msghdr is always empty (excpet the payload size). If I set to 16 then I get some data like:
msg_out: RecvMsgOut { header: io_uring_recvmsg_out { namelen: 16, controllen: 0, payloadlen: 5, flags: 0 }, msghdr_name_len: 16, name_data: [2, 0, 129, 54, 127, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], control_data: [], payload_data: [107, 107, 107, 107, 10] }
payload: "kkkk\n"
buffer: [16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 129, 54, 127, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 107, 107, 107, 107, 10]
name_data: [2, 0, 129, 54, 127, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

But I don't know how to interpret this. How do I use this data to create a file descriptor for SendMsg?
Should I maybe set somehow the IP_PKTINFO flag?
EDIT: it seems the interesting bytes are:
[2, 0, 129, 54, 127, 0, 0, 1]
Which means protocol af_inet (2), then byte (0) which I don't know what it is, then bytes (129, 54) which should be the port, and bytes (127, 0, 0, 1) for address.
I think.
Still not sure how to parse the bytes from the port

Can you elaborate why you're confused about your first snippet? Why wouldn't it work?

What are you calling that gives you the output from your second code block? You should add your [mre] within the question, external links only are not sufficient for various reasons.

@cafce25 why exactly 16? why not 8 or something else?

@cafce25 I added a minimum reproducible example. I use type::parse to read the header from the buffer then I print it

It's not reproducible: What's vec, types, buf_start, buf_end, please use a new project / the Playground to create something truely reproducible and copy & paste it here.

129,54 is the port number in network byte order.

@user207421 yes you're right, I made it work in the end but still can't understand msg_hdr.msg_namelen = 16;, I will update the question with the stuff I found.
I'm trying to read libc to understand how and what they're doing.
